# Eigenvalues of block matrices related

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let,

$C= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}_{n \times n}$

What are the eigenvalues of matrix $C$. Also how to find eigenvalues of following block matrix.

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
B & C \\ 
C^T & O
\end{bmatrix} $

Where $B$ is a square matrix of order $n$ and $O$ is zero matrix of order $n$.

I know that one eigenvalue of matrix $C$ is $2$ as addition of entries in each row is $2$.But how to find other eigenvalues?

Also for block matrix,if we can convert the matrix in terms of knonecker product or direct-sum of two matrices then we can find the eigenvalues easily.But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the bottom of the matrix doen't seem to be in coherence with the top. Could you describe precisely for which values of $i$ and $j$ we have $a_{ij}=1$?

Comment: Except 1st row in all other rows it is in consecutively placed till last rows as shown in matrix

Comment: Consecutive 1s  is not possible with this single rule. It can't be a square matrix.

Comment: The rule mentioned in your last comment is not possible for $i=n$.

Comment: I think now its ok

Comment: Just ignore my comment on $a_{ij}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand $\det(C-\lambda I)$. You should find
$$\chi_C(\lambda)=(1-\lambda)^n+(-1)^{n-1}.$$

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

$C$ is a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues), with $c_k=\delta_{0k}+\delta_{1k}$.

Its eigenvalues are
$$ \lambda_j = 1+\mathrm{e}^{2\pi i \frac{n-1}{n}j} $$